# Installing firefox extension for all users [system wide installation]

Tags: firefox, installation, firefox-addon, mozilla

I have written a Firefox extension which is packed as  an `.xpi` file. I want to install this extension for all users. Somewhere I found that we can achieve this by putting the file in the `Mozilla\Extensions` folder, then the extension will be available to all users.

But the problem is after installing the extension, on first launch of Firefox

- for an administrator, a pop-up tab will appear to ask whether to enable or disable the extension, but
- for the non-admin user, no pop-up will be there and the extension will be disabled for them initially.

Is it possible to notify every user by launching a pop-up tab when they  start the browser the first time after installation?

Comment: Preferably without a pop-up, but if it only works with a pop-up, that would be ok, too.

Comment: If there is no other answer, you can get the bounty just for filing a bug report and posting it here

Comment: I think you are here on the wrong side of the moon, try this one https://lists.mozilla.org/listinfo/addons-user-experience

Comment: @eichertc: only saw it now, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just to provide [the old answer](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Installing_extensions), which no longer worked flawlessly:

> If you want to do a silent administrative install [...]:
>
> uncompress the .xpi file yourself (as a ZIP file) to an appropriately named (extension's ID) folder. On Linux/Unix platforms you can use a helper script to determine extension IDs in an automated fashion.

Put this directory into the `browser/extension` folder.

See also [this answer about Thunderbird](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/220804/115933) (by me). The same steps worked for Firefox before application signing was enforced. In Firefox 43, the signature checks [can be disabled via `about:config`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31952727/how-can-i-disable-firefox-addons-signature-checking) The `about:config` workaround will supposedly stop working in Firefox 44.

Comment: Can you update this answer to also cover firefox installation using snap?