# How to install a Firefox for Andriod add-on without Firefox checking that it has been verified or "signed"

Tags: android, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-android

I found a solution for desktop, but I need one for Android. I have developed a Firefox for Android add-on. I need it private to do my research. However, is there any way to install it without Firefox checking that it has been verified, or "signed". My Firefox for Android version is 51.0.1.

Comment: Have you tried what is detailed in [Installing unsigned XPIs in Firefox for Android version 42 or newer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38803218/3773011)?