# Easy way to debug Firefox for Android add-on JavaScript

Tags: javascript, android, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions, firefox-android

Is there an efficient way to debug my extension's JavaScript (add-on) for Firefox for Android? I developed an Android Firefox add-on. However, I have a hard time debugging the code. Every time I changed the code, I had to sign it and install on my Android device (to see if it works or not). This is time consuming for me. Even when I merely changed a semicolon (`;`), I had to sign and install it again.

Is there an easy way to debugging my extension JavaScript add-on for Firefox for Android? Is there an easy way to develop a WebExtension for Firefox for Android?

Comment: Does that mean you tried what is in [Installing unsigned XPIs in Firefox for Android version 42 or newer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38803218) and it did not work for you?

Comment: Would a reasonable solution be to disable the check for add-on signing using another add-on, and then be able to change your in-development add-on as much as you desire?