# Firefox Add-on does not install when running jpm with --profile argument set

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, jpm

For add-ons that use local storage a profile must be maintained between tests.  In order to do this the "--profile" argument is specified.

I found the above information in [this tutorial on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/simple-storage#Simple_storage_and_jpm_run)

My problem is that when I have a profile specified I get a ton of debugging info and my add on appears to not be installed at all.  It's neither on the topbar, or anywhere I've yet found in my add-ons list.  If I `jpm run` without a `--profile` specified, it works just fine (although storage is not maintained between tests).

Why is my add-on not showing up whenever I specify a user profile?

Below is the debugging info:

```
Sephs-MBP:FF_BlackLister seph$ jpm run --no-copy --profile /Users/seph/Code/Web/FF_BlackLister/user
JPM [info] Starting jpm run on Black Lister
JPM [info] Using provided profile:
JPM [info]     /Users/seph/Code/Web/FF_BlackLister/user
1468181342154   addons.manager  DEBUG   Loaded provider scope for resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm: ["XPIProvider"]
1468181342157   addons.manager  DEBUG   Loaded provider scope for resource://gre/modules/LightweightThemeManager.jsm: ["LightweightThemeManager"]
1468181342166   addons.manager  DEBUG   Loaded provider scope for resource://gre/modules/addons/GMPProvider.jsm
1468181342197   addons.manager  DEBUG   Loaded provider scope for resource://gre/modules/addons/PluginProvider.jsm
1468181342199   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: XPIProvider
1468181342226   addons.xpi  DEBUG   startup
1468181342284   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping @ffblacklister to /Users/seph/Code/Web/FF_BlackLister/user/extensions/@ffblacklister.xpi
1468181342284   addons.xpi  INFO    SystemAddonInstallLocation directory is missing
1468181342285   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping e10srollout@mozilla.org to /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/features/e10srollout@mozilla.org.xpi
1468181342285   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping firefox@getpocket.com to /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/features/firefox@getpocket.com.xpi
1468181342286   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping loop@mozilla.org to /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/features/loop@mozilla.org.xpi
1468181342287   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} to /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/extensions/{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}.xpi
1468181342288   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Skipping unavailable install location app-system-share
1468181342289   addons.xpi  DEBUG   checkForChanges
1468181342291   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Loaded add-on state from prefs: {"app-profile":{"@ffblacklister":{"d":"/Users/seph/Code/Web/FF_BlackLister/user/extensions/@ffblacklister.xpi","e":false,"v":"0.0.1","st":1468181245000}},"app-system-defaults":{"e10srollout@mozilla.org":{"d":"/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/features/e10srollout@mozilla.org.xpi","e":true,"v":"1.0","st":1465405240000},"firefox@getpocket.com":{"d":"/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/features/firefox@getpocket.com.xpi","e":true,"v":"1.0.2","st":1465405240000},"loop@mozilla.org":{"d":"/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/features/loop@mozilla.org.xpi","e":true,"v":"1.3.2","st":1465405240000}},"app-global":{"{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}":{"d":"/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/extensions/{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}.xpi","e":true,"v":"47.0","st":1465405240000}}}
1468181342296   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Changed add-on @ffblacklister in app-profile
1468181342297   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of e10srollout@mozilla.org
1468181342298   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Changed add-on e10srollout@mozilla.org in app-system-defaults
1468181342298   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of firefox@getpocket.com
1468181342299   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Changed add-on firefox@getpocket.com in app-system-defaults
1468181342300   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of loop@mozilla.org
1468181342300   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Changed add-on loop@mozilla.org in app-system-defaults
1468181342301   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}
1468181342303   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Changed add-on {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} in app-global
1468181342304   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getInstallState changed: true, state: {"app-profile":{"@ffblacklister":{"d":"/Users/seph/Code/Web/FF_BlackLister/user/extensions/@ffblacklister.xpi","e":false,"v":"0.0.1","st":1468181341000}},"app-system-defaults":{"e10srollout@mozilla.org":{"d":"/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/features/e10srollout@mozilla.org.xpi","e":true,"v":"1.0","st":1465405240000},"firefox@getpocket.com":{"d":"/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/features/firefox@getpocket.com.xpi","e":true,"v":"1.0.2","st":1465405240000},"loop@mozilla.org":{"d":"/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/features/loop@mozilla.org.xpi","e":true,"v":"1.3.2","st":1465405240000}},"app-global":{"{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}":{"d":"/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/extensions/{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}.xpi","e":true,"v":"47.0","st":1465405240000}}}
1468181342317   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Opening XPI database /Users/seph/Code/Web/FF_BlackLister/user/extensions.json
1468181342320   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Successfully read XPI database
1468181342322   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Add-on @ffblacklister modified in app-profile
*** Blocklist::_loadBlocklistFromFile: blocklist is disabled
1468181342343   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1468181342354   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1468181342356   addons.xpi-utils    INFO    Hiding the updated system add-ons.
1468181342357   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering startup change 'changed' for @ffblacklister
1468181342367   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Loading bootstrap scope from /Users/seph/Code/Web/FF_BlackLister/user/extensions/@ffblacklister.xpi
1468181342510   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method install on @ffblacklister version 0.0.1
1468181342511   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Make addon app-profile:@ffblacklister visible
1468181342512   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1468181342512   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Make addon app-system-defaults:e10srollout@mozilla.org visible
1468181342515   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1468181342517   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Make addon app-system-defaults:firefox@getpocket.com visible
1468181342517   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1468181342518   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Make addon app-system-defaults:loop@mozilla.org visible
1468181342518   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1468181342518   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Make addon app-global:{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} visible
1468181342519   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1468181342519   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Updating XPIState for {"id":"@ffblacklister","syncGUID":"JC-IS0gqH15R","location":"app-profile","version":"0.0.1","type":"extension","internalName":null,"updateURL":null,"updateKey":null,"optionsURL":null,"optionsType":null,"aboutURL":null,"icons":{},"iconURL":null,"icon64URL":null,"defaultLocale":{"name":"Black Lister","description":"An add-on for blaming the sites you hate out of your life","creator":"Seph Reed","homepageURL":null},"visible":true,"active":false,"userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":true,"descriptor":"/Users/seph/Code/Web/FF_BlackLister/user/extensions/@ffblacklister.xpi","installDate":1468181245000,"updateDate":1468181341000,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1,"bootstrap":true,"skinnable":false,"size":18690251,"sourceURI":null,"releaseNotesURI":null,"softDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":true,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"strictCompatibility":false,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"38.0a1","maxVersion":"*"},{"id":"{aa3c5121-dab2-40e2-81ca-7ea25febc110}","minVersion":"38.0a1","maxVersion":"*"}],"targetPlatforms":[],"multiprocessCompatible":false,"signedState":0,"seen":true}
1468181342520   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Updating XPIState for {"id":"e10srollout@mozilla.org","syncGUID":"gqY9JuXdNhOL","location":"app-system-defaults","version":"1.0","type":"extension","internalName":null,"updateURL":null,"updateKey":null,"optionsURL":null,"optionsType":null,"aboutURL":null,"icons":{},"iconURL":null,"icon64URL":null,"defaultLocale":{"name":"Multi-process staged rollout","description":"Staged rollout of Firefox multi-process feature.","creator":null,"homepageURL":null},"visible":true,"active":true,"userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"descriptor":"/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/features/e10srollout@mozilla.org.xpi","installDate":1465405240000,"updateDate":1465405240000,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1,"bootstrap":true,"skinnable":false,"size":4580,"sourceURI":null,"releaseNotesURI":null,"softDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"strictCompatibility":false,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"47.0","maxVersion":"47.0"}],"targetPlatforms":[],"multiprocessCompatible":false,"seen":true}
1468181342520   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Updating XPIState for {"id":"firefox@getpocket.com","syncGUID":"37I8nWPw54eL","location":"app-system-defaults","version":"1.0.2","type":"extension","internalName":null,"updateURL":null,"updateKey":null,"optionsURL":null,"optionsType":null,"aboutURL":null,"icons":{},"iconURL":null,"icon64URL":null,"defaultLocale":{"name":"Pocket","description":"When you find something you want to view later, put it in Pocket.","creator":null,"homepageURL":null},"visible":true,"active":true,"userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"descriptor":"/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/features/firefox@getpocket.com.xpi","installDate":1465405240000,"updateDate":1465405240000,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1,"bootstrap":true,"skinnable":false,"size":894473,"sourceURI":null,"releaseNotesURI":null,"softDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"strictCompatibility":false,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"47.0","maxVersion":"47.0"}],"targetPlatforms":[],"multiprocessCompatible":false,"seen":true}
1468181342521   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Updating XPIState for {"id":"loop@mozilla.org","syncGUID":"EsGzSs3uVtZA","location":"app-system-defaults","version":"1.3.2","type":"extension","internalName":null,"updateURL":null,"updateKey":null,"optionsURL":null,"optionsType":null,"aboutURL":null,"icons":{},"iconURL":null,"icon64URL":null,"defaultLocale":{"name":"Firefox Hello","description":"Web sharing for Firefox","creator":"Mozilla","homepageURL":null},"visible":true,"active":true,"userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"descriptor":"/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/features/loop@mozilla.org.xpi","installDate":1465405240000,"updateDate":1465405240000,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1,"bootstrap":true,"skinnable":false,"size":4239140,"sourceURI":null,"releaseNotesURI":null,"softDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"strictCompatibility":false,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"46.0a1","maxVersion":"47.*"},{"id":"xpcshell@tests.mozilla.org","minVersion":"0","maxVersion":"10"}],"targetPlatforms":[],"multiprocessCompatible":false,"seen":true}
1468181342521   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Updating XPIState for {"id":"{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}","syncGUID":"cKXBy6w3PDjK","location":"app-global","version":"47.0","type":"theme","internalName":"classic/1.0","updateURL":null,"updateKey":null,"optionsURL":null,"optionsType":null,"aboutURL":null,"icons":{"32":"icon.png","48":"icon.png"},"iconURL":null,"icon64URL":null,"defaultLocale":{"name":"Default","description":"The default theme.","creator":"Mozilla","homepageURL":null,"contributors":["Mozilla Contributors"]},"visible":true,"active":true,"userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"descriptor":"/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/extensions/{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}.xpi","installDate":1465405240000,"updateDate":1465405240000,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1,"skinnable":true,"size":7134,"sourceURI":null,"releaseNotesURI":null,"softDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"strictCompatibility":true,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"47.0","maxVersion":"47.0"}],"targetPlatforms":[],"seen":true}
1468181342522   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1468181342522   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Updating database with changes to installed add-ons
1468181342523   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Updating add-on states
1468181342524   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Writing add-ons list
1468181342526   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/features/e10srollout@mozilla.org.xpi
1468181342527   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Loading bootstrap scope from /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/features/e10srollout@mozilla.org.xpi
1468181342530   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on e10srollout@mozilla.org version 1.0
1468181342531   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/features/firefox@getpocket.com.xpi
1468181342532   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Loading bootstrap scope from /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/features/firefox@getpocket.com.xpi
1468181342538   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on firefox@getpocket.com version 1.0.2
1468181342540   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/features/loop@mozilla.org.xpi
1468181342540   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Loading bootstrap scope from /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/features/loop@mozilla.org.xpi
1468181342553   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on loop@mozilla.org version 1.3.2
1468181342593   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1468181342594   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: XPIProvider
1468181342594   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: LightweightThemeManager
1468181342594   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1468181342595   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: LightweightThemeManager
1468181342599   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: GMPProvider
1468181342616   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
1468181342618   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: GMPProvider
1468181342630   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PluginProvider
1468181342630   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
1468181342631   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PluginProvider
1468181342632   addons.manager  DEBUG   Completed startup sequence
1468181342989   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting timer
1468181343005   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: <unnamed-provider>
1468181343005   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
1468181343006   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: <unnamed-provider>
1468181343062   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting write
1468181343307   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PreviousExperimentProvider
1468181343307   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
1468181343307   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PreviousExperimentProvider
1468181343322   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
1468181343322   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   XPI Database saved, setting schema version preference to 17
1468181350757   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method shutdown on e10srollout@mozilla.org version 1.0
1468181350758   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method shutdown on firefox@getpocket.com version 1.0.2
1468181350759   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method shutdown on loop@mozilla.org version 1.3.2
1468181351110   addons.manager  DEBUG   shutdown
1468181351111   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1468181351112   addons.xpi  DEBUG   shutdown
1468181351113   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   shutdown
1468181351116   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1468181351119   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
1468181351123   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
1468181351125   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
1468181351130   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
1468181351133   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Notifying XPI shutdown observers
1468181351139   addons.manager  DEBUG   Async provider shutdown done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It ends up, in my case, I was having an issue with signature checking.  There is [a question about disabling it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31952727/how-can-i-disable-firefox-addons-signature-checking/36284395#36284395) which explains in more detail what signature checking is, but the short of it is:

1. Go to about:config (enter it into address bar)
2. Set xpinstall.signatures.required to false.

This fixed the problem for me.  I also disabled xpinstall.whitelist though I'm uncertain of it's effect.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this is very interesting. I wasn't familiar with the `xpinstall.whitelist.required` pref, just the `xpinstall.signatures.required`.