# avoid Firefox checks that it has been verified or "signed" for android add-on

Tags: android, firefox, firefox-addon

I developed firefox android  add-on. I need it private  to do my research. However,   is there any way to install it without Firefox checks that it has been verified or "signed".  My firefox version is 51.0.1

Comment: Specifically, this answer shows how to disable add-on signing for all add-ons in a profile: [How can I disable signature checking for Firefox add-ons?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42403531)

Comment: The proposed duplicate is probably what you are looking for, but you may also be asking about installing it during development. If so, see: [Installing add-ons for development](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firefox-addon/3235/getting-started-with-firefox-addon/27246/installing-add-ons-for-development#t=201703161730038798357) in Documentation.

Comment: @Makyen Thanks, All these solutions  are proposed for desktop. my target is a android device. how to avoid Firefox checks that it has been verified or “signed” for android add-on

Comment: Then [edit] that information into your question.