# Web-extension opening url on addon install works fine on Opera and Chrome but fails on Firefox?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions, browser-addons

The following web-extension code in my background script `background.js` works fine on Opera and Chrome triggering appropriate webpage on Install, Update and Uninstall but does nothing in firefox. The same is shown as compatible here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/onInstalled

`Manifest.json` has:

```
"background" : {
    "scripts" : ["includes/background.js"]
},
```

`background.js` has :

```
//CHECK INSTALL, UPDATE, UNINSTALL
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function (details) {
    if (details.reason == "install") {
        chrome.tabs.create({
            url : "https://www.example.com/install.html"
        });
    }

    if (details.reason == "update") {
        chrome.tabs.create({
            url : "https://www.example.com/update.html"
        });
    }
});

chrome.runtime.setUninstallURL("http://www.example.com/uninstall.html");
```

Comment: Maybe an error occurs before that code runs. Check the debugger console for your extension.

Comment: No error on the console :(

Comment: In what version of Firefox are you testing?

Comment: @Makyen FF 52.0.1 (32 bit), also, just found that removing addon from the `about:addons` triggers the uninstall-page, still no luck with install and update trigger. Can it be the fact that `Install` is not triggered when in `Debug` mode!!

Comment: Have you actually *fully installed* your add-on? Specifically: Have you installed it as a temporary add-on (i.e. through `about:debugging`)?  If so, [it is documented](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/onInstalled#Compatibility_notes) that it will not work. The event is not fired for temporary add-ons.

Comment: @Makyen Yes, that was the cause, missed that crucial information :(, how to test it with FULL-INSTALL without signing?

Comment: I guess this - https://wiki.mozilla.org/Add-ons/Extension_Signing will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have installed your add-on as a [temporary add-on](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Temporary_Installation_in_Firefox) through `about:debugging`.  The [documentation states](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/onInstalled#Compatibility_notes):

> This event is not triggered for temporarily installed add-ons.

Thus, the event won't fire.  You will need to install your add-on as a normal, non-temporary add-on. There are multiple ways for you to do so.  The official way is to install [Firefox Developer Edition](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer/), or [Firefox Nightly](https://nightly.mozilla.org/) and set `xpinstall.signatures.required` to `false` in `about:config`. If you want to do so in the release version of Firefox, you can [entirely disable add-on signature checking in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42403531/3773011). The process to do so is described in the linked answer (also listed below). You may also the information in the Documentation link below helpful in installing your add-on as a normal add-on.

- [How can I disable signature checking for Firefox add-ons?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42403531/3773011)
- [Installing add-ons for development](https://web.archive.org/web/20170910020945/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firefox-addon/3235/getting-started-with-firefox-addon/27246/installing-add-ons-for-development#t=201709100209448888249) (an archive of Stack Overflow Documentation)