# Globally install a signed add-on

Tags: installation, firefox-addon

Is there any way to [globally install](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Installing_extensions#Global_installation) a signed addon (extension)?

- copying the file to the installation directory did not do anything
- starting Firefox as the owning user of `/usr/lib/firefox-addons/extensions/` did not work (I set the group id to mine and did a `chgrp 775`).
- I had previously offered a bounty on [Installing firefox extension for all users [system wide installation]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12251625/installing-firefox-extension-for-all-users-system-wide-installation), but to no avail. That contains the old procedure that worked.

When you unpack the `.xpi`-file, the signatures do not match the unpacked files.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signatures just seemed different because the `sha1sum` tool gives its output in hex, while the signatures in the manifest file are in base64.

Apart from this, it seems to be an intermittent problem in some Ubuntu releases, as described in [this mailing list post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/mozilla.addons.user-experience/global/mozilla.addons.user-experience/KqA-YVJssLg/xCQ_bGwhCgAJ).

Answer (score 1):

The mozillazine wiki page may be outdated, try the [install locations listed on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Installing_extensions#Linux)

Comment: Thanks. For unsigned, it worked with the mozillazine-given locations. Does using the other locations (`/usr/lib/Mozilla/extensions`) avoid the signing problem?

Comment: i doubt that the locations make a difference wrt signing